# Quanteda kwic append data to output

Tags: r

I'd like to append some metadata to the kwic output such as a customer ID (see below) so that it's easy to lookup against a master file. I've tried appending data using cbind but nothing matches up correctly.

If this is possible examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
     docname    position    contextPre      keyword    contextPost          CustID
     text3790     5    nothing at all looks  good   and sounds great           1
     text3801    11    think the offer is a  good   value and has a lot        3
     text3874    10    not so sure thats a   good   word to use                5
```

originating data.frame

```
       CustID   Comment
         1      nothing at all looks good and sounds great
         2      did not see anything that was very appealing
         3      I think the offer is a good value and has a lot of potential
         4      these items look terrible how are you still in business
         5      not so sure thats a good word to use
         6      having a hard time believing some place would sell an item so low
         7      it may be worth investing in some additional equipment
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first I thought the ideal solution is to use `docvars`, but kwic don't seem to have an option to show them. I still need to merge a id-doc mapping table with the kwic result.

```
library(data.table)
library(quanteda)

s <- "CustID,   Comment
1,      nothing at all looks good and sounds great
2,      did not see anything that was very appealing
3,      I think the offer is a good value and has a lot of potential
4,      these items look terrible how are you still in business
5,      not so sure thats a good word to use
6,      having a hard time believing some place would sell an item so low
7,      it may be worth investing in some additional equipment"

# I'm using data.table mainly to read the data easily. 
dt <- fread(s, data.table=FALSE)

# all operations below apply to data frame
myCorpus <- corpus(df$Comment)
# the Corpus and CustID came from same data frame, 
# thus ensured the mapping is correct
docvars(myCorpus, "CustID") <- df$CustID
summary(myCorpus)
# build the mapping table of docname and CustID. 
# The docname is in row.names, have to make an explicit column
dv_table <- docvars(myCorpus)
id_table <- data.frame(docname = row.names(dv_table), CustID = dv_table$CustID)
result <- kwic(myCorpus, "good", window = 3, valuetype = "glob")
id_result <- merge(result, id_table, by = "docname")
```

result:

```
> id_result
  docname position   contextPre keyword      contextPost CustID
1   text1        5 at all looks    good and sounds great      1
2   text3        7   offer is a    good value and has         3
3   text5        6 sure thats a    good word to use           5
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was slowly coming to the realization that some type of merge or join was going to be required. It would be a nice feature in KWIC if you could also include other columns from the originating data frame as part of the output. Cheers.

Comment: KWIC probably will not be aware of other columns in original data frame, because it is working on corpus, and corpus was designed to read from other types of data instead of data frame. We can add columns to `docvar`, which can be accesses by KWIC if the author want. Though the package author seemed to be only using them for plot or reports of corpus.

Comment: thanks @Pierre Lafortune, didn't know the `data.table=FALSE` option before!

Answer (score 1):

It is a `data.frame` object so you can add columns the regular way:

```
library(quanteda)
h <- head(kwic(inaugTexts, "secure*", window = 3, valuetype = "glob"))

#Add new ID column
h$CustID <- 1:nrow(h)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Adding a new column works but ultimately I'm after assigning the correct customer ID to their statement(s).

Comment: You can do that also. Why didn't you supply the id mapping in the question?

Comment: Thats what I'm asking, how to put these pieces of the puzzle together.

Comment: Where are your customer ids now?

Comment: Got you...data.frame

Comment: It appears that the id column is in the same order as the kwic output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123185/discussion-between-pierre-lafortune-and-atwp67).

Comment: Modified to keep things easy, guess that's not helping

Comment: the dataframe at the bottom is just a `select() and mutate()` version of the top data frame.  What exactly do you want to do? merge the frames?

Comment: @Imkirvan      What I want to do is take the customer ID from the main data.frame and append to the KWIC output. The top output is what I envision.